# Null Pointer exception

Tags: android, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception

I am trying do `HTTP POST` using `AsyncTask`. I have to create `Response` class, because we cannot extend more than one class. In `Response` class, I take response of HTTP request, then start new activities according to response. Line:  `responseClass.responseFunction(response);` is throwing NullPointer Exception. How can I take `response` from login method?

```
public class Login extends AsyncTask <String, Void, Void>  {

    Response responseClass = new Response ();

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {
        String email = strings[0];
        String password = strings[1];

        login(email, password);

        return null;
    }

    public void login(String email, String password) {
        HttpURLConnection connection;
        OutputStreamWriter request = null;

        URL url = null;
        String response = null;
        String parameters = "email=" + email + "&password=" + password;

        try {
            url = new URL("url");
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

            request = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
            request.write(parameters);
            request.flush();
            request.close();
            String line = "";
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }

            System.out.println("parameter: " + parameters);
            // Response from server after login process will be stored in response variable.
            response = sb.toString();
            isr.close();
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Error

        }
        System.out.print("response" +response);
        responseClass.responseFunction(response);

    }

    class Response extends AppCompatActivity{

        public void responseFunction(String response){

           if(response.charAt(0) == '1'){

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "e-mail veya şifre hatalı!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        else if(response.charAt(0) == '0'){
            System.out.print("Sonucc1");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Başarıyla giriş yapıldı!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            //session.createLoginSession(email,password);
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Amount.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else if(response.charAt(0)== '2'){
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Geçerli bir e-mail adresi giriniz!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else if(response.charAt(0)=='3'){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Şifre 6 karakterden kısa olamaz!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            }
        }

    }
}
```

Here is LogCat:

```
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                       Process: com.example.merve.tev, PID: 20768
                                                       java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                           at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:109)
                                                           at com.example.merve.tev.Login$Response.responseFunction(Login.java:97)
                                                           at com.example.merve.tev.Login.login(Login.java:82)
                                                           at com.example.merve.tev.Login.doInBackground(Login.java:31)
                                                           at com.example.merve.tev.LoginActivity$1.onClick(LoginActivity.java:54)
                                                           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
                                                           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Line 97: Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Başarıyla giriş yapıldı!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: I don't see where `responseClass` is being assigned a value.  It also doesn't appear to be getting injected in.

Comment: did you get that ?? You are missing initialization of the responseClass variable...

Response responseClass = new Response();

Comment: I initialized responseClass. However, NullPointer Exception is throwing again. @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @Tim in the comments, you just need to initialise your `responseClass` variable. Maybe you would like to do this as follows :

```
public class Login extends AsyncTask <String, Void, Void>  {

    Response responseClass = new Response(); // initialisation

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {
       ...
       ...
```

Comment: I initialized `responseClass`, however, NullPointer Exception is throwing again.

Comment: Update your question with the exact error logcat.

Comment: Is the `response` itself null?

Comment: Also, add `e.printStackTrace()` inside your `catch` block.

Comment: I edited my question. Response is not null.

Comment: Though that's horrible code, you can try to send a context object as an argument to `responseFunction()` and use that context for the intents too.

Comment: Or maybe try to use your Activity's context instead of `Application` context

Comment: Thanks for quick reply! Why this is horrible code? I am new to programming and Android world. I am trying to improve myself. @ZeekHuge

Comment: 1st -  You prevent using Application context unless you really know why you need it. 2nd - An activity object is something that you 'start' using intents and then process something inside it for the UI part. You do not just create it to get the a 'context' without starting it

Answer (score 0):

The error is happened because you always set null for the response string at `String response = null;`. You haven't give any string for exception. Hence the `responseClass.responseFunction(response);` will receive `null` string every time the code facing an exception. Then it will throwing Null Pointer Exception.

```
public void login(String email, String password) {
   ...
   // You always set response as null
   String response = null;
   try {
      ...
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
         sb.append(line + "\n");
      }
      ...
      response = sb.toString();
          ...
   } catch (IOException e) {
      // Error
      // But here you don't set any string for response
   }

   // Hence the response will be null an throw an exception.
   System.out.print("response" +response);
   responseClass.responseFunction(response);
}
```